# What is wrong in this function? It regularly shows syntax error when I run ng serve (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Every time when I run ng serve it throws a syntax error and either says; is missing or ) is missing or , is missing. The fun part is that you can remove one ; for example and click save it will start running perfectly the next time when you type ng serve it shows similar error and you add the same , or ; which removed last time and it starts working again until the next ng serve. Here is the code:

```
 OnFileSelected(event) {
    const file: File = event[0];

    this.ReadAsBase64(file)
      .then(result => {
        this.selectedFile = result;
      })
      .catch (err => {this.error = err; setTimeout(() => {this.error = ''; }, 2000; } );  )

  }
```

All these errors with `, ; ) or }` are happening here:

```
 .catch (err => {this.error = err; setTimeout(() => {this.error = ''; }, 2000; } );  )

      }
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: They say, you can try to use newline characters by pressing `Enter` (it's a big button on your keyboard). Then you can read the code better. And btw, this is off topic on SO because this is all about typo-like error

Comment: I would also remove any whitespaces to make it even harder to read)

Comment: You guys are evil..just as his code

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
.catch(err => { this.error = err; setTimeout(() => { this.error = ''; }, 2000) }  )
```

or better be

```
const file: File = event[0];

this.ReadAsBase64(file)
    .then((result) => {
        this.selectedFile = result;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        this.error = err;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.error = '';
        }, 2000);
    });
```

as it is easier to read, you placed the semicolons and brackets in wrong places